# node elastic search strict match

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

can anyone tell me how to strict match in elasticsearch-js. here is my search

```
client.search({{
  index: 'hash_tag',
  type: 'hash_tag',
  lenient:false,
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        tag_name: 'hash tag 1'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (body) {
    console.log("body", JSON.stringify(body));
  }, function (error) {
    console.trace(error.message);
})
```

this query search either **hash, tag ,1** i'm looking for exact whole string match.here is my example index style.

```
{
  "_index": "hash_tag",
  "_type": "hash_tag",
  "_id": "3483",
  "_score": 0.019691018,
  "_source": {
    "id": "3483",
    "labels": [
      "hash_tag"
    ],
    "tag_name": "hash tag 2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default elasticsearch will "tokenize" your text fields to add them to the inverted index, that's why you get results for each term used.

In order to get the full match you can have different approaches, the simplest would be to use a [match_frase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_phrase_search.html):

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
"query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "about" : "rock climbing"
    }
  }
}
```

Another option would be to add that specific field with a mapping of not_analyzed, then the text wouldn't be tokenized.